# Where to add license of windward in .net core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, windward

I am new to windward & I want to use .net core with windward restful engine.Where I can add windward license in .net core.I am getting windward license excpetion in .net core

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Windward products don't yet support .NET Core, but you can use our RESTful engine which has to be hosted on a Windows Server running IIS and it will answer POSTs and GETs from your .NET Core application.

If you have more questions, please contact Windward Support at support@windwardstudios.com.